# Abgezeichnete einzelne Banane

Tags: meaning

**Meine Frage bezieht sich auf das Wort:**

> abgezeichnete

[image]

Heute im REAL. Die Bananen liegen auf dem Tisch. Das Schild "abgezeichnete einzelne Banane" steht dahinter.

Was bedeutet in dem Fall die Phrase `abgezeichnete einzelne Banane`?
Warum empfiehlt Google Translate nichts Sinnvolles?
Warum empfiehlt Google Translate das Wort "**ab**gezeichnete" mit dem Wort "gezeichnete" ersetzen?

Kann man die eigentlich gratis mitnehmen?
Darf man je eine für ein Baby/Erwachsenen mitnehmen?

[image]

Comment: Deine letzten zwei Sätze sind mir ein Rätsel. Mit dem Rest der Frage kann ich mit viel Fantasie was anfangen. Aber ein bisschen mehr Kontext wäre schon gut.

Comment: Die Nominalgruppe *»abgezeichnete einzelne Banane«* ist ja schon deutsch. Was soll man da noch übersetzen?

Comment: Hmm... ich dahte, es it üblich. Das Kontext habe ich hinzugefügt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, _"marked single banana"_ - does it make any sense?

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown I'd suspect it means the bananas on the table are already weighted, and will be scanned correctly as you're going to the cashier. I see no notice that these could be taken away for free.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown: I don't know. This here is a board about **german** language, and I am a german native speaker. Questions that would need an expertise in an other language than German are off-topic and have be closes. Also question about translations of individual texts are off-topic and have to be closed too.

Comment: Ich bin zu Real gefahren um zu ein Foto aufzumachen.

Comment: Das arme Foto. Was macht man mit offenen Fotos eigentlich?

Comment: @Janka, leider kann ich Ihre Phrase (oben) nicht verstehen. Was bedeutet es?

Comment: Weiß ich auch nicht. Bei real,– macht eben der Praktikant vom Praktikanten die Schilder, weil man den weder mit Ware noch Kunden zusammenbringen darf. Mit Papier offensichtlich auch nicht. Aus dem Zusammenhang: *Diese Bananen haben wir einzeln abgewogen und mit Preis ausgezeichnet. Ihre Kinder können sie also schon beim Warten in der Schlange futtern und wir piepsen dann den Aufkleber.*

Comment: @Janka, ich denke Interface Unknown bezieht sich auf etwas anderes ;) Man sagt nicht "ein Foto aufmachen", sondern "ein Foto machen" oder "ein Foto aufnehmen". "Ein Foto aufmachen" wäre etwas wie "to open a photo", und mit dieser Idee hat Janka ein Wortspiel gemacht.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck, vielen Dank! Das war natürlich mein Fehler. Klar musste ich sagen "ich habe das Foto aufgenommen". (Manchmal ist der Weg zur Wahrheit sehr schwierig.. ;)

Comment: Und ich dachte, Interface Unknown hat ein Wortspiel gemacht.

Comment: Hat sich der Fragesteller Gedanken gemacht, wer eigentlich Antwort geben könnte auf Fragen wie "Warum macht Google Translate dies und das"?

Comment: As a comment: deepl.com and linguee.com are in my experience much better than google translate

Comment: Weder sieht man einzelne Bananen, noch einen Preis auf einzelnen Bananen oder etwas anderes, das den Begriff "Zeichen" verdient. Abgezeichnet könnte sich auf etwas Abstraktes beziehen, aber die Auseinanderschreibung von "Sofortverzehr" und die Ausrufezeichendolde deuten darauf hin, dass der, der das Schild machte, nicht sprachsicher ist. Gäbe es bei großer Hitze Getränke für Kinder zum Sofortverzehr könnte ich das nachvollziehen, oder wenn die ausgesonderten Bananen Druckstellen hätten oder wenn es zumindest lose Bananen wären.

Comment: So wie hier präsentiert halte ich die Frage für nicht beantwortbar. Frag doch bitte im Supermarkt selbst - die sollten es wissen.

Comment: Frage 4 und 5 kann man verneinen. Das Schild erlaubt keine Mitnahme, sondern nur den sofortigen Verzehr. "Sofortiger Verzehr" könnte auch heißen, dass das MHD abgelaufen ist, und man sie zügig verzehren soll, aber nicht gleich im Laden. Dann wundert aber die Einschränkung auf Kinder. Auch ist "abgezeichnet"  kein Synonym für "abgelaufen", während die Nähe von "unterzeichnen/unterschreiben" eine Verwechslung von "abgezeichnet/abgeschrieben" denkbar erscheinen lässt. Sollte der Laden in CH oder AUT liegen, dann bitte die Information nachtragen - dort hat man teils hier unüblichen Wortgebrauch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, mit dem Foto ist die Sache klar. Hier ist offenbar "abgezeichnet" als ein Ausdruck aus dem Fachjargon der Handels gemeint. Ich hatte schon in meiner ursprünglichen Antwort geschrieben, dass "auszeichnen" bedeuten kann, etwas mit einem Preisschild zu versehen. Entsprechend kann "abzeichnen" vermutlich bedeuten, ein vorhandenes Preisschild wieder zu entfernen. Falls hier jemand aus dem Handel mitliest, ist das so richtig? Die Bananen sind also offenbar abgezeichnet, der Händler möchte sie nicht mehr verkaufen.

Diese einzelnen Bananen sind tatsächlich ein Angebot des Händlers an seine "kleinen Kunden", also die Kinder der Käufer im Laden. Die können sich eine Banane nehmen und sofort essen. Es wird von vielen Läden geduldet, wenn ein Kind es nicht abwarten kann und zum Beispiel eine Banane bereits im Laden verspeist. Das darf man eigentlich nicht, aber es wird oft geduldet. Hier hat offenbar ein Händler ein eigenes Angebot für solche Fälle gemacht. Ob der Händler es auch dulden würde, wenn ein Erwachsener eine der Bananen isst oder man eine Banane mit nach Hause nimmt, weiß ich nicht. Es ist aber so gedacht, dass Kinder im Laden eine von den Bananen essen können.

Anstelle von "zum sofort verzehr" wäre eigentlich "zum sofortigen Verzehr" oder "zum Sofortverzehr" richtig.

---

(*Ursprüngliche Antwort*) Vermutlich stand auf dem Schild nicht "abgezeichnet", sondern "ausgezeichnet". Ich kann mir eine Formulierung wie

> Bananen, einzeln ausgezeichnet

vorstellen. "Ausgezeichnet" soll in diesem Fall kein Qualitätsmerkmal bedeuten ("die Banane schmeckt ausgezeichnet"), sondern dass der Preis auf der einzelnen Banane steht. Wenn man Waren mit einem Preisschild versieht, sagt man auch, man zeichnet die Ware aus.

Und Du kannst es als Faustregel nehmen: In einem Laden kostet *alles* etwas, außer es ist ausdrücklich als kostenlos gekennzeichnet. Dazu ist ein Laden da, um Dinge zu verkaufen ;)

Comment: Das Foto ist da oben.

Comment: Als erstes ist festzuhalten, dass auf dem Foto keine einzelne Banane zu sehen ist - vielleicht ganz links, aber ich bezweifle es. Unklar ist auch, was diese Bananen auszeichnet, so dass sie nicht normal verkauft werden.

Comment: @userunknown Das "einzelne" bedeutet wohl vor allem, dass die "kleinen Kunden" sich jeweils nur eine Banane nehmen und essen sollen, und nicht gleich ein ganzes Bündel einsacken. Und die Bananen müssen nicht unbedingt ein Manko haben. Vielleicht investiert der Händler einfach nur ein wenig Ware, die er eigentlich hätte verkaufen können, um seinen Kunden einen zusätzlichen Service zu bieten. Das ist aber natürlich nur Spekulation.

Comment: Das ist sehr viel Spekulation, aber auch einzelne Bananen sollen nicht eingesackt, sondern lediglich sofort verzehrt werden. Dass nach dem Verzehr einer einzelnen Banane nicht eine weitere, einzelne Banane verzehrt werden soll/darf sehe ich nicht kommuniziert. Deutsch lernen kann man mit dem Schild nicht.

Comment: "wenn ein Erwachsener eine der Bananen isst oder man eine Banane mit nach Hause nimmt" - deshalb steht da ja extra, das Angebot sei für die "kleinen Kunden", also nur für Kinder. Ich verstehe es allerdings in der Tat so, dass diese Bananen kostenlos sind - nicht zuletzt, weil ich ansonsten den Preis auf dem großen Schild oben erwarten würde. "zum sofort verzehr" würde ich als klare Kennzeichnung als "kostenlos" sehen, denn was man sofort verzehrt, kann an der Kasse auch nicht registriert werden. Dadurch, dass Kunden mit satten/mampfenden Kindern ggf. auch länger bleiben und mehr kaufen ...

Comment: ... als Kunden mit hungrigen quengelnden Kindern, fände ich es auch nicht weiters überraschend, dass für diese Bananen kein Geld verlangt wird. (Selbes Prinzip wie bei kostenfrei benutzbaren Spielecken etc.)

Answer (score 4):

*Abzeichnen* ist hier synonym zu *abschreiben*, im Sinne von *to write off*. Im Handel wird mit damit der Vorgang bezeichnet, mit dem die Wertminderung durch Verlust oder Verderb erfasst wird, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abschreibung. Daher kommt auch die Redewendung *Das kannst du abschreiben*, i.e. "Das kannst du als verloren betrachten", "Das kannst du unter Verlust verbuchen", auch über Personen als *Den kannst du abschreiben*, d.h. "Auf den kannst du nicht rechnen", "Den kannst du vergessen".

Dass die Bananen "abgezeichnet" sind, soll demnach ausdrücken, dass der Händler nicht mehr davon ausgeht, sie noch verkaufen zu können, und sie als Verlust verbucht hat. Möglicherweise liegt in der Verwendung des Verbs "abzeichnen" ein nicht besonders üblicher Sprachgebrauch vor, vielleicht schlicht eine Verwechslung mit "abschreiben". Das Personal in Supermärkten ist nicht immer der Rechtschreibung mächtig - wie sich im Bild auch an dem orthographischen Fehler "sofort verzehr" andeutet, was nach amtlicher Rechtschreibung entweder "zum sofortigen Verzehr", oder "zum Sofortverzehr" oder allenfalls "zum Sofort-Verzehr" heißen müsste.

Comment: Soweit man die Bananen auf dem Foto sieht, spricht nichts dafür, dass die Bananen unverkäuflich sind. Dazu kommt, dass sie gar nicht einzeln sind.

Comment: @userunknown In dem Supermarkt, in dem ich gearbeitet habe, wurden solche Bananen abgeschrieben, weil sie sich nicht mehr verkaufen. Sieht krass aus, weil die Bananen ja wirklich noch gut sind - sonst könnte man sie ja auch nicht an Kinder verschenken - ist aber leider Realität in deutschen Supermärkten.

Comment: Bananen, die äußere, dunkle Flecken aufweisen, dürfen natürlich verkauft werden. Ob sie sich gut verkaufen lassen ist eine andere Frage. Ein Supermarkt, in dem man sich rasch sein Frühstück holt, kann auch einzelne Bananen verkaufen. Ich habe bereits mehr als 1x einzelne Bananen gekauft.

Comment: @userunknown Ich verstehe nicht, worüber wir hier diskutieren. Ich dachte, du stellst in Frage, dass "abgezeichnet" hier synonym zu "abgeschrieben" bedeutet - mit dem Argument, dass die Bananen ja noch gut aussehen. So hatte ich deinen Beitrag verstanden. Darauf habe ich versucht, zu antworten, dass das Abschreiben solcher Bananen wie auf dem Foto gang und gäbe ist - sodass das also nicht gegen meine ursprüngliche These spricht, dass "abgezeichnet" hier bedeutet, dass die Bananen aus dem Verkauf genommen wurden.

Comment: Im ersten Satz schreibst Du, dass Abzeichnen hier synonym zu Abschreiben ist, als gesicherten Fakt. Dann räsonnierst Du über das Synonym Abschreiben, was nur durch die Behauptung, dass es ein Synonym ist, gerechtfertigt wird. Erste Mitte des zweiten Absatzes rürckst Du mit der These raus, dass es mlöglicherweise eine Wortverwechslung ist. Was aber dafür spricht, dass die Bananen abgeschrieben sind, schreibst Du nicht und ich behaupte, dass das Foto dazu auch nichts hergibt. Die Bananen sind noch vollkommen in Ordnung. Mir scheint du schließt aus der Abschreibung, dass sie es nicht sind, und …

Comment: … aus dem Schluss schließt Du wieder zurück, dass Abgeschrieben gemeint ist. Das ist ein klassischer Zirkelschluss.

Comment: @userknown Jetzt verstehe ich dich, denke ich. Der augenscheinliche Zirkelschluss beruht auf meinem Weltwissen, dass solche Bananen wie die abgebildeten regelmäßig abgeschrieben werden. Außerdem passt es ansonsten gut in den Kontext des Bildes. "einzelne" Bananen verstehe ich so, dass eine Banane je Kunde / je Kind genommen werden soll. Man kann das sicher auch anders interpretieren. Sicher ist die Kommunikation hier durch die mangelnde Ausdruckskraft der Person, die das Schild geschrieben hat, gestört. Daher kann ich mir gut vorstellen, dass ich mich in meiner Interpretation täusche.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94504/discussion-between-jonathan-scholbach-and-user-unknown).

Answer (score 1):

> Darf man je eine für ein Baby/Erwachsenen mitnehmen?

Neben den schon richtigen Antworten möchte ich kurz bemerken, daß in Deutschland solche Schilder "leider" ernst zu nehmen sind. Du solltest dich nicht als Erwachsener dort hinstellen und diese im Laden verzehren, auch das Einstecken ist nicht gerne gesehen.
Es wird keiner die Polizei rufen, allerdings kannst du dir eine Bemerkung einfangen oder wirst dafür schief angeschaut. Es ist leider sehr üblich viele Waren zu entsorgen, um den "Qualitätsanspruch" zu wahren. Von daher sind solche Aktionen sehr selten, ggf. werden Waren auch nur rabattiert.

Comment: Soweit man die Bananen auf dem Foto sieht, spricht nichts dafür, dass die Bananen unverkäuflich sind. Dazu kommt, dass sie gar nicht einzeln sind.